# Fast 2D cumsum of sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix, cumsum

The clearest way to ask this question may be to develop it in stages...

### Q1: General case

Consider that `cumsum(x)[i]` could be defined (for all i) as `sum(x[1:i])`.

Also consider the generalization `cumsum2D(A)[i,j]` defined (for all i,j) as `sum(A[1:i,1:j])`. This is similar to the way integrals are generalized to 2 dimensions.

```
> # Example
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    1
[3,]    0    1    0
> cumsum2D(A)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    2
[3,]    0    2    3
```

Let Q1 be the question: What is the fastest/best way to calculate `cumsum2D(A)` in R, assuming `A` is large? This question is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519717/cumulative-sum-in-a-matrix).

### Q2: Sparse case

Note that any matrix `A` can be represented as a data frame (call it `D`) listing its non-zero elements. `D$val` contains `A[A!=0]` while `D$i` and `D$j` contain the corresponding subscripts. If `A` is sparse `nrow(D)` is small.

Let `cumsum2Dsparse(D)` be equal to `cumsum2D(A)`.

```
# Example
> D
  i j val
1 1 2   1
2 2 3   1
3 3 2   1
> cumsum2Dsparse(D)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    2
[3,]    0    2    3
```

Let Q2 be the question: What is the fastest/best way to calculate `cumsum2Dsparse(D)`, assuming `D` represents a matrix that is sparse?

### Q3: Special sparse case

Now suppose each row and each column of `A` contains only 1 non-zero element. (Or equivalently, suppose `D$i` and `D$j` are permutations of `1:nrow(A)` and `1:ncol(A)` respectively.)

Let Q3 be Q2 given this constraint.

### Qk

As already mentioned, Q1 has been [answered on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519717/cumulative-sum-in-a-matrix).

Q2 is the sparse version of Q1.

I include Q3 because it may have a faster solution than Q2, but if you feel it is too specific/unreusable, just ignore it.

EDIT: For reference:

- In keeping with the sparseness of Q3,
  let N = number of columns = number of rows = number of non-zero elements.
- For benchmarking, use the data
  `D <- data.frame(i=1:10000,j=((1:10000)*3333)%%10000,val=1)`

Comment: For a sparse matrix D, you can get the cumulative sum for each element in O(N^2) where N is the number of non-zero elements in D.

For each element, just keep adding the sum if the element in consideration lies in the top-left portion of the matrix. This can be done by comparing their i's and j's.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm unsure how you get to O(N^2). Are you looping only over non-zero entries in the outer loop? If so, what about elements such as [3,3] in the example's cumulative sum above?

Comment: Yes you are right. Outer loop should run for each element in the matrix.

Comment: @Abhishek So that leaves us with O(nrow*ncol*N). I think even the unsparse case can be done in O(nrow*ncol). I guess we're stuck with O(nrow*ncol) if we want the entire output matrix.