# How to make rows in a data frame accumulative from right to left

Tags: r

I have a matrix like

```
> A= [ 1 2 4
>      2 3 1
>      3 1 2 ]
```

and I would like to have result accumulative by each row from right to left like:

```
> A= [ 7 6 4
>      6 4 1
>      6 3 2 ]
```

I tried to use the solution in [Cumulative sum in a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519717/cumulative-sum-in-a-matrix) but it gives a different way of adding the matrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit magical, but:

```
t(apply(A,1,function(x) rev(cumsum(rev(x)))))
```

does it.

- `apply(A, 1, FUN)` applies a function to each row of the matrix.
- `rev()` reverses the vector and `cumsum()` computes the cumulative sum: we need `rev(cumsum(rev(x)))` to get the ordering you want
- the final `t()` is necessary to transpose the results because `apply` *always returns its results column-wise*, as (very obscurely) noted here (from the "Value" section of `?apply`):

> If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’
>        returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned `data.frame` in the title, and there is a way of using `Reduce` and `rev` with a data.frame to get the result you want.

```
A <- data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,1),c(4,1,2))
data.frame(rev(Reduce("+",rev(A),accumulate=TRUE)))
  c.7..6..6. c.6..4..3. c.4..1..2.
1          7          6          4
2          6          4          1
3          6          3          2
```